# Flask - What is difference when returning jsonify vs dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, httpresponse

I have route which returns response to the user on `POST` request. I am returning a `dict` on request. The problem is for some cases returning a dict works fine, but sometimes throws an error.

Can anyone please explain what is the ideal return type and why the `dict` return is successful for some of the cases ?

```
@app.route('/getuser', methods = ['post'] )
def getusername():
    user = request.json.get("user_name")

    # This works good for few cases
    return {"username": user}

    # Whereas other require this
    return jsonify({"username": user})
```

Answer (score 11):

**TLDR**: *There is no difference.*

---

Basic example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/getuser_dict', methods=['POST'])
def getuser_dict():
    user = request.json.get("user_name")
    return {"username": user}


@app.route('/getuser_jsonify', methods=['POST'])
def getuser_jsonify():
    user = request.json.get("user_name")
    return jsonify({"username": user})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Sending `POST` request and retrieving response from both `/getuser_dict` and `/getuser_jsonify` are same (*irrelevant parts left out*):

```
> POST ...
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: insomnia/7.0.3
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 24

| {
|   "user_name": "John"
| }

* upload completely sent off: 24 out of 24 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body

< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 20
< Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.6.8
< Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 09:34:51 GMT


* Received 20 B chunk
* Closing connection 65
```

Returning `dict` internally only checks what type of object are you returning, is it `string`, `tuple`, `BaseResponse` or `dict`. When it determines you really return `dict` by `isinstance(rv, dict)`, it calls `jsonify(rv)` on your `dict` object and returns.

Please take a look at [make_response](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/d091bb00c0358e9f30006a064f3dbb671b99aeae/src/flask/app.py#L1935) method of `app.py`. The part where it [checks is it a dict object](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/d091bb00c0358e9f30006a064f3dbb671b99aeae/src/flask/app.py#L2017) is also there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Which one is considered more elegant?  The first option for being simpler or the second option for being explicit?

Comment: Both ways work, so you can use what you find more suitable to you. For me personally, I use  the first approach because I mostly do some "proof of concept" and I find it easier to write.